# Word for people who run, but not standard marathon distances

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

I regularly participate in *mini-marathons* (as they are sometime unofficially locally called) that happen around my area. I started with 5 KM and over a couple of years have improved my distance to 10 KM. But this is still not what a marathon or a half marathon would constitute.

I want to write about my interest in running on my resume/website. What would be appropriate?

I am a runner.

I am a mini-marathon runner.

I am a long-distance runner.

Or something else, as the distance doesn't seem to be sufficient for it to be related to marathons or long distance running.

Comment: You can simply say "distance runner", because that's the primary challenge you're setting yourself, as opposed to *speed*, or *competitive*, etc.

Comment: You are a "runner".  In the US that term would lead the listener to assume distances of a few miles if nothing more were specified, though you can add, eg, "I sometimes do mini marathons."

Comment: [Everyone gets a trophy](http://www.reddit.com/r/TrueAskReddit/comments/1x4rkj/where_and_how_did_the_now_infamous_every_child/).

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to get so detailed on your resume. The person reading it won't care. "Running" is more than enough.

Comment: @Barmar: In fact, I'd say that 'running' is far more than enough.  (Assuming that you're not applying for some athletics-related job.)  I don't think personal details that are irrelevant to the job belong on a resume.

Comment: It's not uncommon to have a brief "Personal interests" section at the end of a resume, especially if the resume is very short. No one really cares what it says, it's just a matter of form. Occasionally when you're in an interview with a potential coworker it might spark some conversation.

Comment: While you see it every once in a while, I don't really like the "personal interests" section in resumes, unless they have some relation to the job. Otherwise it's just not helpful. And it almost suggests to me that you hope to get hired because somebody likes/shares your personal interests, and not because of your professional qualifications. Which is really not the signal you want to send. But if you want it on your resume, I share @Barmar's suggestion: "running" is completely sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am a mini-marathon runner.

If I may hazard a guess, you're from India (like me). If so, US idiomatic expressions might not be the best way to put it. (`Distance runner` by Dan Bron is a good one, though.)

Since you need it for your résumé , chances are that the US idioms would be lost on the HR rep going through it.

There's nothing too awkward or wrong with `mini-marathon`, moreover, it's honest and accurate.

Go with it.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of American English speakers would just say, "I run 10Ks".  I believe that's fairly common terminology in the English-speaking world, although I'm a bit leery of saying so as you don't seem familiar with it.

On a list of interests, you could simply put "run 10Ks".